# Amazon Linux + SSL + vhosts

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, apache-2.4, lets-encrypt, amazon-linux

I have a new test instance that I have setup with LAMP and SSL.

I have the following in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webadmin@ohanacruises.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog.ohanacruises.com
    ServerName blog.ohanacruises.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webadmin@ohanacruises.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/travel.ohanacruises.com
    ServerName travel.ohanacruises.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

I then installed mod24_ssl.  HTTPD service will no longer start, until I remove the Virtual Host sections.  Eventually I would like to get SSL certs for each subdomain and add appropriate flags for SSL in the virtual hosts area on the conf file.

Just as a note if I remove the virtual hosts and setup a SINGLE domain in the httpd.conf and ssl.conf files all works with SSL.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to start it?

Comment: I think I was able to fix it by adding SSL cert paths to the vhost sections.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot host multiples certificates on a same IP:PORT at same time. So to solve that problem I follow the tutorial on the following link and it works like a charm.

https://atticuswhite.com/blog/aws-multiple-ssl-certs/